# Control the text in a form

Tags: html, forms

I have a form, I want to :
1- Put a name inside as default
2- When someone clicks in the form, the default text gets outs and they can write. When they click outside the text that they have written is still there to be send.
3- When someone clicks outside without writing anything the default name comes back

I have tried: onblur="(this.value='nom') But when the user writes and he clicks outside, what he wrote is deleted.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="titol" value="nom" onClick="(this.value='')"  " />
</form>
```

I have the example here:
http://jsbin.com/aposun/1/edit

Comment: why don't you use placeholder instead? <input type="text" name="titol" value="nom" placeholder="default value"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your input:

```
<input type="text" name="titol" value="nom" 
   onfocus="if (this.value=='nom') this.value = '';" 
   onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'nom';"
/>
```

In HTML5 you could use `placeholder` instead:

```
<input type="text" id="titol" name="titol" placeholder="nom" />
```

Comment: I didn't know about the placeholder, Its a good solution. But for non html5 browsers, I don't understand your solution I try it here http://jsbin.com/aposun/5/edit and I don't see the advantage to the solution that I already provided:http://jsbin.com/aposun/1/edit Are they equivalent or am I missing something?

Comment: In my solution I only clear the value if it's the original placeholder. I don't clear user input as you do. Excepting one situation - when user inputs the same value ;)

Comment: Ah! ok!! your solution is better because when the user writes his name and later clicks a second time, his name don't get deleted. It's an important improvement but still there is the problem num "3. When someone clicks outside without writing anything, the default name should come back"

Comment: Just add onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='nom';".. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML 5 element placeholder as mentioned on the last 2 replies, however if you need support for any olders or IE browsers then you will need to use a javascript alternative too. But be careful because they can be a bit of a pain with regards validation if it's a required field. I would prefer to not have it populated and give a help icon instead.

However here is a nice article on the javascript way of doing it: [Javascript default text](http://robertnyman.com/2011/05/02/html5-placeholder-and-an-alternative-approach-introducing-roberts-playground/)

Answer (score 0):

As they have said above you can use the placeholder attribute in html5, I'm not really sure about the browser support though so I've modified your code and simply compare what you have as your default value, if its the default value it won't clear the text field:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" name="titol" id="titol"   /><br />
</form>

</body>
  <script>
    var val = "nom";
    var titol = document.getElementById('titol');
    titol.value = val;

    titol.addEventListener('click', function(){
      if(this.value == val){
         this.value = "";
      }
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't know about the placeholder. I's good to know,thank you very much. But I need a solution for IE8 an other non html5 borwsers. I don't understand your solution, I try it: http://jsbin.com/aposun/5/edit and I don't see the difference. Am I missing something?